# С# приведение к типу при десериализации по дескриптору. Ряд дескрипторов на один класс

Tags: c#, xml

Нужно иметь возможность при десериализации приводить `Main.Property` к `A:BaseType`, `В:BaseType` и к `BaseType`. Проблема в том, что ряд дескрипторов (C, D, E) должны приводить к `BaseType` (или к какому-то 1 типу).

Используя `[XmlInclude(typeof(A))]` `[XmlInclude(typeof(B))]`, как подсказали раньше, получаем xml типа `<BaseType xsi:type="A" type="A">`. Все хорошо, кроме того, что невозможно привести и `<BaseType xsi:type="С" type="С">`, и `<BaseType xsi:type="D" type="D">, <BaseType xsi:type="E" type="E">` к BaseType. Возможно создать одинаковые классы С, D, E, но это некрасиво и убивает идею.

Есть ли способ выкрутится?

```
class Main
{
    public BaseType Property { get; set; }
}

class BaseType
{
    public string Descriptor { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно. У вас _уже есть_ типы `C`, `D` и `E`? Тогда почему нельзя добавить `XmlInclude`? Или у вас нет таких типов, откуда тогда у вас они взялись в XML? В общем, опишите свою _настоящую_ задачу.

Comment: А приведите реальный пример, чтобы было легче понять. Абстрактные А, В, С, D, E ни о чем не говорят, т.е. мне, например, непонятно, чем плохи С, D, E и почему они одинаковые.

Comment: @VladD, С, D, E это декларация в XML, в коде они должны быть представленны одним классом, например BaseType.

Comment: @andreycha С, D, E = один класс в С#, в идеале BaseType.

Comment: @sss: А в какой из `C`, `D`, `E` должен тогда отображаться `BaseType`?

Comment: @VladD, если  я правильно понял, то пока хватит хотя бы десериализации. То есть <root><property xsi:type="С" type="С"></root><root><property xsi:type="D" type="D"></root><root><property xsi:type="E" type="E"></root> должны десериализоваться с типом BaseType.

Comment: @sss: Просто если вам хочется неоднозначного мэппинга XML на классы, то [тут что-то не так](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Возможно, вам нужна не сериализация, а честный парсинг.